# How do split the list items and save in csv file in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list as follows

```
mylist = ['item1 : server1 server2 server3 server4', 'item2 : server2, server5, server6', 'item3 :' , 'item4 : server11 server12 server13']
```

I would like save the the mylist into csv file as follows

```
item1     item2    item3      item4
====================================
server1  server2            server11
server2  server5            server12
server3  server6            server13 
server4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it into a data frame and use the `to_csv()` function for writing it to file as a csv.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
mylist = ['item1 : server1 server2 server3 server4', 'item2 : server2, server5, server6', 'item3 :' , 'item4 : server11 server12 server13']
myData = []
for i in mylist:
    t = i.split(':')[1]
    t = t.split(' ')[1:]
    myData.append(t)
my_df = pd.DataFrame(myData).T
my_df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', index=False, header=['item1','item2','item3','item3'])
```

And while reading, use :

```
pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv')
df = df.fillna('')              #This line will replace the null values, which are NaN now with an empty string.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do:

```
import csv

mylist = ['item1 : server1 server2 server3 server4', 'item2 : server2, server5, server6', 'item3 :' , 'item4 : server11 server12 server13']


mylist_split = [item.replace(':', '').replace(',','').split() for item in mylist]

with open("my_csv_file.csv", 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='|', quotechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    _max_row = max([len(item) for item in mylist_split])
    for i in range(_max_row):
        row = list()
        for item in mylist_split:
            if len(item) > i:
                row.append(item[i])
            else:
                row.append('')
        print(row)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

First, I split your initial list in sub-list. So, each element in these sub-list is a case in the csv.
Then I use the `csv` library, the `csv.QUOTE_ALL` is just here to have the good number of space (or `quotemark`).
In the `for loop`, I created each row, because your elements were ordered by columns, I go through each element each time.
 I use a `if statement` because all your columns do not have the same number of element, so I ensure the rows will have empty space if the columns is already ended.

If someone knows how to replace the `.replace().replace()` by something more clever I will be happy to know.

Comment: The only way I see to get rid of one `.replace` is by stripping the comma on the output `row.append(item[i].strip(','))`. But I'm not sure there is a more clever way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

If style is important to you (I mean for your csv file). You can use this code:

```py
mylist = ['item1 : server1 server2 server3 server4', 'item2 : server2, server5, server6', 'item3 :' , 'item4 : server11 server12 server13']

clean = lambda x: x.replace(',', '').split(' :')
titles = [clean(it)[0] for it in mylist]
values = [clean(it)[1].strip().split() for it in mylist]

csv = ('{:<9} ' * len(titles)).format(*titles) + '\n'
csv += '=' * 10 * len(titles) + '\n'

for i in range(len(titles)):
    items = [v[i] if len(v) > i else '' for v in values]
    csv += ('{:<9} ' * len(titles)).format(*items) + '\n'

with open('output.csv', 'w+') as fp:
    fp.write(csv)
```